# SQL - compare a non related table

Tags: sql

Need to retrieve information from 2 tables that are not related on a sql db. Basically
I need to view the name, salary AND salary_grade, according to lower_bound or upper_bound.

table A:

1. name
2. salary

Table B:

1. salary_grade
2. lower_bound
3. upper_bound

For example John has a salary of $1000

{salary_grade, lower bound, upper bound}: {1, 800, 999}, {2, 1000, 1200} ...

so this view would bring fields "John" + "1000" + "2".
As you see there is no foreign key or way to relate both tables and i'm struggling to find out a function to relate em.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply write a join using BETWEEN:

```
SELECT a.name, a.salary, b.salary_grade
FROM a JOIN b 
ON a.salary BETWEEN b.lower_bound AND b.upper_bound
```